# Struggling to implement SMILES2vec RNN from DeepChem for fitting on FreeSolv Dataset leading to negative R^2

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to use a SMILES2vec model from Deepchem in order to reproduce the regression results from the original paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.02034.pdf). Towards this end, rather than using the model directly from DeepChem, I used tensorflow to throw the model together using sequential, and used the architecture that fed the embeddings into a 1D convolution and 2 LSTMs. I don't have any errors, but I've used coefficient of determination as my error metric and it comes out negative. This happened regardless when I've tried bidirectional() on the LSTMs and I've switched from MSE to MAE loss, and I'm still not sure what to do. The dataset I'm training on is FreeSolv from deepchem.

```
!pip install --pre deepchem
!pip install rdkit-pypi
!pip install tensorflow-addons

tasks, dataset, transformers = dc.molnet.load_freesolv()
train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = dataset

smiles_list = [x for x in itertools.chain(train_dataset.ids, valid_dataset.ids, test_dataset.ids)]

charset = set("".join(list(smiles_list))+"!E")
char_to_int = dict((c,i) for i,c in enumerate(charset))
int_to_char = dict((i,c) for i,c in enumerate(charset))
embed = max([len(smile) for smile in smiles_list]) + 5

## converts SMILES strings to embedding or vector
def vectorize(smiles):
    one_hot =  np.zeros((smiles.shape[0], embed , len(charset)),dtype=np.int8)
    for i,smile in enumerate(smiles):
        #encode the startchar
        one_hot[i,0,char_to_int["!"]] = 1
        #encode the rest of the chars
        for j,c in enumerate(smile):
            one_hot[i,j+1,char_to_int[c]] = 1
        #Encode endchar
        one_hot[i,len(smile)+1:,char_to_int["E"]] = 1
    return one_hot[:,0:-1,:], one_hot[:,1:,:]

def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
    def lr(y_true, y_pred):
        return optimizer.lr
    return lr

#Prepare features for SMILES2vec
X_train, _ = vectorize(train_dataset.ids)
X_valid, _ = vectorize(valid_dataset.ids)
X_test, _ = vectorize(test_dataset.ids)

Y_train = train_dataset.y
Y_valid = valid_dataset.y
Y_test = test_dataset.y

vocab_size=len(charset)

## Build model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=embed-1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(192,10,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())                            
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(224,return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(384,return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))

## Coefficient of determination metric
def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
    from keras import backend as K
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred ))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) )
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
lr_metric = get_lr_metric(optimizer)
model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(), coeff_determination, lr_metric])

callbacks_list = [
    ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=5, min_lr=1e-3, verbose=1, mode='auto',cooldown=0),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.best.hdf5", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    
]
history =model.fit(x=np.argmax(X_train, axis=2), y=Y_train,
                              batch_size=32,
                              epochs=50,
                              validation_data=(np.argmax(X_valid, axis=2),Y_valid),
                              callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

If it helps at all, I'm running this on a google colab notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pJ25THeefBWUpe73cL_1LNnq45Pd95XZ?usp=sharing

As to why I'm not using the DeepChem implementation of SMILES2vec, I wanted to 1. get more hands-on work with building models with tensorflow and 2. I struggled with trying to get the DeepChem implementation running just form using DeepChem's Documentation (https://deepchem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/models.html). However, I want to focus on why my coefficient of determination is reaching negative scores. Additionally, I've been trying to use this notebook for reference which uses a 'proof of concept' implementation of SMILES2vec where the LSTMs are replaced with 1D conv layers (https://github.com/Abdulk084/Smiles2vec/blob/master/smiles2vec.ipynb).